# will socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP) stop all the datagrams going to the right places?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

So I created a socket with socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP). And then I have it recv() with a infinite loop. I know it can captures all datagrams. But will it stop datagrams going to the right places? I made a little experiment. I send very simple UDP message from one program to another. And they both received the message.
I assume the raw socket won't block any UDP messages. I then read about it in [the second paragraph of this question's best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057029/do-i-have-to-bind-a-udp-socket-in-my-client-program-to-receive-data-i-always-g). It says an unbound udp socket will mess up the system. So I am not sure that is the same with raw socket. Or is it different on linux and windows?

And another quick question: binding socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP) with a port won't do anything, right? I did it and the socket still receive messages going to all kinds of other ports.

Comment: I am having the same problem in Linux. I have a Linux server using raw UDP sockets (IPPROTO_UDP) and it is able to receive and send but the client (using SOCK_DGRAM) does not receive it even though the server receives the packet it just sent.... Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: BTW, I also tried to bind() the local address of the client but still didn't get the response from the server. I see the server receives the message it sends and also see it in Wireshark....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not.  Raw sockets deliver all packets to all registered socket users, so you'll get a copy of the packet as soon as it is got into the system, but a UDP socket will receive it also.

To the second question... you don't `bind(2)` a raw socket, so you cannot associate it with a port number.